# Use Tooltip in Kendo (MVC)

Tags: templates, kendo-ui, format

This demo : http://dojo.telerik.com/akom
How to can show : "Total Visit: $5600" when hover mouse in chart.
I try this code:

`tooltip: {
            template: "#= series.name #: #=value#", 
            visible: true, 
            format: "{0:C}"
            }`

Comment: Please, improve the description of your problem. The example referred in http://dojo.telerik.com/akom already shows "Total Visit" when mouse hover. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: if you can provide jsfiddle or more code than we can be able to reproduce the problem and can provide solution for it..

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add the currency format against the value and no need to set format. Please see below:

```
tooltip: {
          template: "#= series.name #: #=kendo.toString(value,'c2')#",
          visible: true
         }
```

Here 2 specifies the number of decimal places you want in your currency. So if you dont want any then set it as c0.